# Oracle agregate by ID with time range

Tags: sql, oracle, join, aggregate

I'm sure I saw it somewhere, but I cannot find it.
Given this table Historic:

| ID1 | ID2 | Event_Date | Label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-08 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-20 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-30 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-04 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-08 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-20 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-30 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-02 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-04 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-08 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-20 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-12-30 | 1 |

And the table startingpoint

| ID1 | ID2 | Event_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-02 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-05 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-08 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-21 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-03 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-06 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-11 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-20 |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-12-31 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-03 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-05 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-08 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-21 |
| 2 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |

For each row in startingpoint, compute the number of rows in historic with the same ID1 and ID2, where Event_Date in historic is between StartingPoint.Event_date - n days (I make it n so that I can change for different values) and StartingPoint.Event_date - 2 days. Then use the same rules to compute the fraction of rows with label = 1.

I know I can do this with a join , but if historic and startingpoint are very large, this looks very inefficient (for every row in startingpoint it will create a large join, and in the end it will sumarize the same set of rows many times repetadly). From an abstract point, it looks to me like it would be better to first sumarize historic for every ID1, ID2, Event_date, and the join with the startingpoint and select the best, but I'm open to other solutions.

Comment: You have to join them, so not quite sure what you mean. Might be helpful to include the result you expect for this data, and your current query if you have something that works but you think is inefficient (and why you think that).

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution with subquery:

```
select * ,(select count(*) from historic h where h.id1=s.id1 and h.id2=s.id2 and h.event_date between dateadd(day,-30,s.event_date) and dateadd(day,-2,s.event_date) )from startingpoint  s
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to have some form of join; either joining directly, or with a scalar subquery, which is probably not going to be as efficient.

The simplest way to do this is probably just a plain join, if you only want to see rows which have historic data:

```
select sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date,
  count(h.event_date) as any_label,
  count(case when h.label = 1 then h.label end) as label_1,
  count(case when h.label = 1 then h.label end) / count(h.event_date) as fraction_1
from startingpoint sp
join historic h on h.id1 = sp.id1
and h.id2 = sp.id2
and h.event_date >= sp.event_date - 10
and h.event_date < sp.event_date - 2
group by sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date
order by sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date;
```

where *n* is 10; which with your data would give you:

```
ID1 ID2 EVENT_DATE ANY_LABEL LABEL_1           FRACTION_1
--- --- ---------- --------- ------- --------------------
  1   1 2020-01-05         4       3                  .75
  1   1 2020-01-06         4       3                  .75
  1   1 2020-01-08         6       4 .6666666666666666667
  1   1 2020-01-11         8       6                  .75
  1   2 2020-01-05         2       2                    1
  1   2 2020-01-08         3       3                    1
```

Or if you want to see zero counts, you can use an outer join; though then the fraction calculation needs some logic to avoid a divide-by-zero error:

```
select sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date,
  count(h.event_date) as any_label,
  count(case when h.label = 1 then h.label end) as label_1,
  case when count(h.event_date) > 0 then
    count(case when h.label = 1 then h.label end) / count(h.event_date)
  end as fraction_1
from startingpoint sp
left join historic h on h.id1 = sp.id1
and h.id2 = sp.id2
and h.event_date >= sp.event_date - 10
and h.event_date < sp.event_date - 2
group by sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date
order by sp.id1, sp.id2, sp.event_date;
```

which gets:

```
ID1 ID2 EVENT_DATE ANY_LABEL LABEL_1           FRACTION_1
--- --- ---------- --------- ------- --------------------
  1   1 2020-01-01         0       0
  1   1 2020-01-02         0       0
  1   1 2020-01-03         0       0
  1   1 2020-01-05         4       3                  .75
  1   1 2020-01-06         4       3                  .75
  1   1 2020-01-08         6       4 .6666666666666666667
  1   1 2020-01-11         8       6                  .75
  1   1 2020-01-20         0       0
  1   1 2020-01-21         0       0
  1   1 2020-12-31         0       0
  1   1 2021-01-01         0       0
  1   2 2020-01-03         0       0
  1   2 2020-01-05         2       2                    1
  1   2 2020-01-08         3       3                    1
  2   1 2020-01-08         0       0
  2   1 2020-01-21         0       0
  2   1 2021-01-01         0       0
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2a6eb4039890f5cc4f676cbb2396e8f4)